# Ignore block in for each XSL

Tags: xslt

I have the following code below, where I use a for each to go through some data.

It turns out that I need the  lines to be traversed only once per record.

```
<xsl:for-each select="ROWSET/ROW">
    <xsl:if test="col5!=col6">
    <h1><xsl:value-of select="col4"/></h1>
    </xsl:if> 

      <xsl:if test="col11!=col12">
      <p style="width: 988px;height: 40px;font-size: 21px;margin: 21px;font-style: normal;font-weight: bold;"><xsl:value-of select="col13"/></p>
      </xsl:if> 

        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="background-color: #bfbfbf;">Título</th>
                        <th style="background-color: #bfbfbf;">Parcela</th>
                        <th style="background-color: #bfbfbf;">Espécie</th>
                        <th style="background-color: #bfbfbf;">Emissão</th>
                        <th style="background-color: #bfbfbf;">Vencimento</th>
                        <th style="background-color: #bfbfbf;">Atraso</th>
                        <th style="background-color: #bfbfbf;">Vlr. Original</th>
                        <th style="background-color: #bfbfbf;">Vlr. Aberto</th>
                        <th style="background-color: #bfbfbf;">Vlr. Juros</th>
                        <th style="background-color: #bfbfbf;">Vlr. Corrigido</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                  <xsl:if test="col11!=col12">
                    <tr>                               
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="col14"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="col15"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="col16"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="col17"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="col18"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="col19"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="col20"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="col21"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="col22"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="col23"/></td> 
                    </tr>
                  </xsl:if>

                  <xsl:if test="col11=col12">
                    <tr>                               
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="col14"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="col15"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="col16"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="col17"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="col18"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="col19"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="col20"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="col21"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="col22"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="col23"/></td> 
                    </tr>
                  </xsl:if>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

</xsl:for-each>
```

The result I have is this:

[image]

What I need is this:

[image]

Can anyone help in any solution?

Thanks

Comment: No one can help you without the input data. You should add a small sample input XML to your question.

Comment: Those `xsl:if` instruction instead of `xsl:choose` might be symptoms that you haven't grasped XSLT workflow. From your linked images, it looks like you have a grouping problem with flatten data instead of hierarchical data.